# I got a 0.1% improved MSFE result by my own estimator, is this worthwhile to be published?

Tags: forecasting, mse

As the title, recently I developed some nonparametric forecasting method which slightly modified the previous method. Then, I could about 0.1% improved result comparing to the previous method.

But I think this figure is too small, even though the rationale in it is correctly intuitive.

What do you think about proceeding this method to write some paper?

** I think this question might not be appropriate, then any other website or forum would be very helpful for me.

Comment: This is primarily an opinion seeking question, & so off topic. I don't know of any SE forum where this would be appropriate for that reason. OTOH, you could ask in chat.

Comment: It all depends on what you are forecasting, what the "0.1%" represents, and how reproducible this difference is.

Comment: @kurtkim Since the question got closed here, maybe you can ask at http://academia.stackexchange.com/ where such opinion based questions are common, although you will get less statistics specific answers.

Answer (score 3):

During my Ph.D. my advisor was super picky. Basically, if I got sightly better (say 1%) or even a much better (say 20%) performance, that reason alone will not be acceptable for publication.

In any research, you want to **argue why** it will work, instead of the better results you got from your own experiments.

You can ask how people who do peer reviews. When I review other people's work, I would not focus on the experiment / simulation section, because I have no way to verify the procedure and measurements are correct. Even they are correct, getting a better performance without explaining why is not good work because it can come from luck or other uncertain factors.

Instead, I will focus on the methodology section to see if the author can argue the improvement or revision of the exciting work is necessary for specific use case, and the reason can be generalized to work in the future.

Comment: I totally agree with you. As you mentioned, after getting some significant results from some simulations, we need to establish some theorems to verify those results which is a super-difficult work. I'd rather be a bit confident to my result, since it is based on an intuitively correct ground.